# Laravel 5.8 seeding database with many to many relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I currently work with Laravel 5.8 and my database has a `users` table and a `roles` table that are connected by many to many relation. My intention is to seed whole database in one go using `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` however pivot table `role_user` is always empty, suggesting that something is not right with attach/sync. I intend on implementing more many-to-many relations so I want thoroughly understand seeding these relations using seeders and factories.

How can I seed many-to-many relations and quickly check if these relations are working correctly?

User Model:

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        //Default variables generated by Laravel
        public function roles()
        {
           return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user')->withTimestamps();
        }
    }
```

Role Model:

```
class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'role_user')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Table role_user migration:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
    }
```

Role Seeder:

```
public function run()
{
    $role_user = new Role();
    $role_user->role = 'user';
    $role_user->save();

    $role_admin = new Role();
    $role_admin->role = 'admin';
    $role_admin->save();
}
```

User Seeder:

```
 public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

        $role_user = Role::where('role','=','user')->first();
        $role_admin  = Role::where('role','=','admin')->first();

        //Generic user account for testing
        $test_user = new User();
        $test_user->username = 'user';
        $test_user->email = 'user@example.com';
        $test_user->email_verified_at = now();
        $test_user->password = 'user';
        $test_user->remember_token = Str::random(10);
        $test_user->save();
        $test_user->roles()->attach($role_user);

        //Generic admin account for testing
        $test_admin = new User();
        $test_admin->username = 'admin';
        $test_admin->email = 'admin@example.com';
        $test_admin->email_verified_at = now();
        $test_admin->password = 'admin';
        $test_admin->remember_token = Str::random(10);
        $test_admin->save();
        $test_admin->roles()->attach($role_admin);
    }
```

Comment: What is the `$faker` for? And for me it looks fine...

Comment: I just cut out some lines to keep code concise. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you wanted to use via factory,

Create UserFactory.php in factories folder

```
<?php

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Model Factories
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This directory should contain each of the model factory definitions for
| your application. Factories provide a convenient way to generate new
| model instances for testing / seeding your application's database.
|
*/

$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'username'           => $faker->name , 
        'email'              => $faker->unique()->safeEmail , 
        'email_verified_at ' => Str::random(10),
        'remember_token'     => now(),
        'password'           => Hash::make('123456')
    ];
});
```

Then create RoleUsersFactory.php

```
<?php

use App\User,App\Role,App\RoleUser;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Model Factories
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This directory should contain each of the model factory definitions for
| your application. Factories provide a convenient way to generate new
| model instances for testing / seeding your application's database.
|
*/

$factory->define(App\RoleUser::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'role_id'   => Role::all()->random()->id,
        'user_id'   => User::all()->random()->id,
    ];
});
```

Then in your DatabaseSeeder.php
add this

```
factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function($u) {
    $u->userroles()->save(factory(App\RoleUser::class)->make());
 });
```

One more thing you need to create RoleUser model and in User model you've setup incorrect relationship `role_user` doesn't exist in your role table.

I hope this helps

Comment: This model has to extend Model or Pivot?

Comment: Simply extends model

Comment: I don't get that part about incorrect relationship `role_user`. I thought that second parameter is used to name pivot table. In documentation `role_user`, both singular is naming convention for pivot tables. Could You explain this to me?

Comment: Look at this syntax `return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');` Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: 1 problem: Laravel seeds 100 rows instead of 50. 2 problem: It seeds role_ids higher then 2 and it doesn't work: `'role_id' => Role::where('id','<=','2')->get()->random()->id`. 3 problem: It seeds not unique user_ids.